# Mongodb grouping data - mapReduce or aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565e906bc2209d91c4357b59"),
    "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
    "subscription" : {
        "project1" : {
            "subscribed" : false
        },
        "project2" : {
            "subscribed" : true
        }
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565e906bc2209d91c4357b59"),
    "userEmail" : "mno@example.com",
    "subscription" : {
        "project1" : {
            "subscribed" : true
        },
        "project2" : {
            "subscribed" : true
        },
        "project3" : {
            "subscribed" : true
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to group by users with the list of projects where the `subscribed` flag is set to `true`.

For instance, what I'm expecting is:

```
abc@example.com - project2
mno@example.com - project1,project2,project3
```

I'll have a cron job which will send the respective details on the subscribed projects to the corresponding mail ids.

I tried aggregation, but aggregation needs the key specified. In my case the key (which is Project1, Project2 and so on) is dynamic. So I read somewhere `mapReduce` is the correct option to go for. But I don't have an experience in using `mapReduce`.

Kindly help me to solve this problem and make me to understand with more explanation on how to handle this.

Comment: Maybe [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) could help here to remove the array entries with `subscribed: false`.

Comment: If you change *subscription* to an array [{project:"project1", subscribed:true},...] it can easily be done with the aggregation framework. Otherwise, you have to go with map-reduce or some client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your documents' current structure you need to use [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce).

```js
db.subscription.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var project = [];
        for (key in this.subscription) {     
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.subscription, key) && this.subscription[key]['subscribed']) 
            { project.push(key); } 
        } 
        emit(this.userEmail, project); 
    }, 
    function(key, values) {}, 
    { out: {'inline': 1 } }
)
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "abc@example.com",
                        "value" : [
                                "project2"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "mno@example.com",
                        "value" : [
                                "project1",
                                "project2",
                                "project3"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 28,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 2,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 2
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

---

You should consider to change your document structure. To to that you need to update your document and change "subscription" to and array of sub documents using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulk = db.subscription.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.subscription.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var newSubscriptions = [];
    var subscription = doc.subscription;
    for (key in subscription) {     
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(subscription, key)) 
                newSubscriptions.push( { 'project': key, 'subscribed': subscription[key]['subscribed'] });
    }
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$set': { subscription': newSubscriptions }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 500 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        db.subscription.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// clean up queues
if (count > 0) 
    bulk.execute();
```

After this operation your documents look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("566041212729b51edb5871d4"),
        "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
        "subscription" : [
                {
                        "project" : "project1",
                        "subscribed" : false
                },
                {
                        "project" : "project2",
                        "subscribed" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565e906bc2209d91c4357b59"),
        "userEmail" : "mno@example.com",
        "subscription" : [
                {
                        "project" : "project1",
                        "subscribed" : true
                },
                {
                        "project" : "project2",
                        "subscribed" : true
                },
                {
                        "project" : "project3",
                        "subscribed" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

You can you the `.aggregate()` method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.subscription.aggregate([
    { '$project': {
        'userEmail': 1,
        'projects': {
            '$setDifference': [
                { '$map': {
                    'input': '$subscription', 
                    'as': 'srpt',
                    'in': { '$cond': [ '$$srpt.subscribed', '$$srpt.project', false ] } 
                }}, 
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("566041212729b51edb5871d4"),
        "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
        "projects" : [
                "project2"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565e906bc2209d91c4357b59"),
        "userEmail" : "mno@example.com",
        "projects" : [
                "project1",
                "project2",
                "project3"
        ]
}
```